# how to display my field values in VF PDF from controller class for a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, pdf, custom-controller

my VF code

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
<style>
body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }

@page{
    size: letter;
    margin:10%;
    @top-left{
        content: "Dear,";
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    @bottom-right{
        content: "Yours Sincerely,";
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
}
    </style>
</head>
    <div align="right"><strong>Date</strong>: {!DAY(Today())} {!CASE(MONTH(Today()), 1, 'January', 2, 'February', 3, 'March', 4, 'April', 5, 'May', 6, 'June', 7, 'July', 8, 'August', 9, 'September', 10, 'October', 11, 'November', 12, 'December', 'Unknown')} {!YEAR(Today())}</div>
<center>
    <h1> Letter</h1>
    </center>
    <p>{!custom_object__C.Name__C}</p>    
</apex:page>
```

My contoller class

```
public class MyController {

private final custom_object__c customobject;

    public MyController(){
        customobject = [SELECT Id, Name__c FROM custom_object__c 
                    LIMIT 1];
    }
    public custom_object__c getcustom_object__c(){
        return customobject;
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        update customobject;
        return null;
    }
}
```

I got the error:

> Unknown property 'MyController.custom_object__C'

How to display the field values written in between `<p> </p>` in my VF page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using formula syntax - you need to reference the variable instead of the Object type. Salesforce knows that by `{!Custom_Object__c}` you mean the current record, and if you were using a standard `Custom_Object__c` controller, you'd already be done.

Change the merge field to `{!customobject.Name__c}`. This references your controller's variable, and will display data from that.

Looks like you're missing a getter or setter for your variable. Its also marked as `private` - no other code can view or change this variable.

```
public final Custom_Object__c CustomObject { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Even after changing to {!customobject.Name__c} I got the same compile error Unknown Property: Mycontroller.customobject